# AngularJS custom filter doing infinite loop of filter funtion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a table, which is being populated with data. So, I wanted to write a custom filter which will filter data which lies in some range (Basically a range filter). Sounds easy, but when I implemented it, the filter is being executed infinitely.

Data:

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "columns": [
        {
            "header": "achievedPrice",
            "type": "number",
            "achievedPrice": 33190
        },
        {
            "header": "askingPrice",
            "type": "number",
            "askingPrice": 133
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 82,
    "columns": [
        {
            "header": "achievedPrice",
            "type": "number",
            "achievedPrice": 16784
        },
        {
            "header": "askingPrice",
            "type": "number",
            "askingPrice": 13556
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Table:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in readyData.rows | filter:numRange">
        <td ng-repeat="column in row.columns">
            {{ column[column.header] }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Filter**

```
scope.numRange = function (list) {
                var min = 0; // DUMMY VALUE
                var max = 134; // DUMMY VALUE
                if (list.columns.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < list.columns.length; i += 1) {
                        if (list.columns[i].askingPrice) {
                            if (list.columns[i].askingPrice >= min && list.columns[i].askingPrice <= max) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };
```

It shows up correct data in table, but its executing endlessly. I've tried doing same thing in a fresh page and it works fine there. If I use Angular's filter (just for text filtering) that filter works fine.

Comment: "I've tried doing same thing in a fresh page and it works fine there" , what does that mean?

Comment: Creating a new html page, adding this table there, using same data to populate it and creating same filter there. It works there. Assume it like a local fiddle

Comment: Okay. then u should provide some jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: @Anthony that is if I use it like numRange:what:ever . If used like filter:numRange you need to return boolean

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. There is nothing wrong with this range filter, the object which holds table data also holds some other data, so other data was being used by some component and that component also used filter, so they keep on filtering the main object.

It fix this, I've use "@" in scope of those component directive to make them read-only and not mess up.